# Port 'pop-ups' to new tab browser hack/block pop-ups per ad production agency?

Tags: google-chrome, browser-addons, google-chrome-extensions, spam-prevention, popups

I sometimes feel obligated to accept non-malicious popups that don't contain flash.  Pop-up ads monetize some of my favorite websites, actually.  Unfortunately, regardless of whether or not an ad passes my filter, the pop-up shows.  I might get a [404](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404) because I've altered my Windows [hosts file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29), but the desired effect is to have no pop-up at all, right?  Most pop-up blockers block popups from the site generating the ad objects (the site you surf to), not the site generating the ad class (the ad company's site).

Is there a good pop-up blocker for Chrome that blocks popups by ad company?  **More importantly**, is there a way to port the pop-ups that I do want to see such that they appear in a new tab, rather than a new window?

Comment: Do you use [AdBlock](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adblock/gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom) & [AdBlock Plus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adblock-plus-beta/cfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb)?

Comment: @amiregelz Yes, I am currently using those softwares.